# Is there something like a rolling OutputStream?

Tags: java

Is there a simple Java OutputStream that mimics a functionality similar to the log4j RollingFileAppender ? Basically it would write to a file that grows to a maximum size, then renames it, begins a new one etc. Just thought I'd ask, before writing it from scratch.

Comment: log4j is open source.  Can you adapt the code they've already written?

Comment: I looked into it, but the Rolling file appender is nothing like a Stream and has lots of dependencies of other code portions. I'd probably be able to extract some ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like that in plain java. Once you have a file handle open it's open - and it's up to you to close it :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything like that, but you could probably subclass Apache Commons IO [`ThreadholdingOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/ThresholdingOutputStream.html) to do it.

Comment: Good Idea, that way the buffer could be kept in memory while switching the stream over to a new file. Thanks, will try that

Answer (score 0):

There is [rotating-fos](https://github.com/vy/rotating-fos) that provides a `RotatingFileOutputStream`. Its usage is pretty straigthforward:

```
RotationConfig config = RotationConfig
        .builder()
        .file("/tmp/app.log")
        .filePattern("/tmp/app-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS}.log")
        .policy(new SizeBasedRotationPolicy(5000 /* 5s */, 1024 * 1024 * 100 /* 100MB */))
        .policy(DailyRotationPolicy.getInstance())
        .build();

try (RotatingFileOutputStream stream = new RotatingFileOutputStream(config)) {
    stream.writer("Hello, world!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}
```